# I can send form data using GET method but not POST, why?

Tags: php, html, forms

So I'm trying to learn html+php but it seems like I've hit a wall. If I use the GET method in my html form, parameters are sent to my php file just fine, but if I try to do the same using the POST method no parameters are sent.

@Edit: I've taken down the initial code sample displayed here as I found out its not a problem specific to that code. Instead I'm posting a basic form and a basic php script that have the same problem:

HTML FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="testingForm.php" method="POST">
        INPUT: <input type="text" id="iTesting" name="nTesting"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    /* THIS WORKS: */
    /*if (isset($_GET["nTesting"]))
        echo "It is working! ".$_GET["nTesting"];
    else
        echo "It is NOT working! input: ".$_GET["nTesting"];
    echo "<br/>".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."<br/>";
    echo "<br/>".var_dump($_GET);//*/

    /* THIS DOESN'T: */
    if (isset($_POST["nTesting"]))
        echo "It is working! ".$_POST["nTesting"];
    else
        echo "It is NOT working! input: ".$_POST["nTesting"];
    echo "<br/>".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."<br/>";
    echo "<br/>".var_dump($_POST);//*/
?>
</body>
</html>
```

As stated before, if I change the form method to GET, I get no problem at all. However, data doesn't seem to be sent when using POST method.

This is the output using the GET method:

> It is working! input: test
>
> GET
>
> array(1) { ["nTesting"]=> string(4) "test" }

This is the output using the POST method:

> It is NOT working! input:
>
> POST
>
> array(0) { }

Also, using the developers tool I can see there is a parameter **nTesting:test** in the formData section of the network tab. Yet, nothing is displayed.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @rtfm response for var_dump($_POST); is array(0) { }

Comment: What is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`?

Comment: Go to the Network tab of Developer tools to see what's being sent when you submit the form.

Comment: On the initial view it will always say it's not working, since no form was posted yet. I prefer to add a hidden input in my form and then do `if ((isset($_POST['input'])) && (!empty($_POST['input'])) {...`

Comment: @Barmar well if I echo that I get 'GET' as a response, but I don't know what this is about. Can't I just use both GET and POST methods by default in a website?

Comment: the form and php are separate or the same page ?

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded the changed form to the website? Maybe you got it from cache.

Comment: Go to the Element inspector in Developer tools to see if you see `method="GET"` or `method="POST"`.

Comment: @rtfm they're in separated files, but the GET method is working so I don't think that's the problem... doesn't that mean it should work on the POST method as well?

Comment: @Barmar I cant seem to find any reference to method="GET" or "POST" inspecting elements, besides a weird giant <mytubeelement/> tag which I do not have in my html code. As for the cache question I don't think that's the case.

Comment: Just inspect the `<form>` element. You should see all the attributes in the inspector.

Comment: Are you using a `<script>` element to submit this form?

Comment: @Barmar I do have a method="POST" there actually. Also should update that "echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];" does respond with POST. Still same output though.

Comment: @Kisaragi I am not using a script, only HTML/CSS file and PHP file.

Comment: If `REQUEST_METHOD` says `POST`, then the parameters should be in `$_POST`.

Comment: When you look in the Network tab, does it show any parameters being sent?

Comment: @Barmar it does show "nUsername:iutyituy
nPassword:tyuitiu
x:83
y:37" on the FormData section. Being 'iutyituy' and 'tyuitiu' random input values for the username and password textboxes

Comment: @Barmar seems to me that I am missing something extremely basic and obvious so I'm editing the original thread adding the whole files

Comment: Check your `php.ini` and make sure it has `variables_order=EPGCS`

Comment: I have a section "; variables_order
;   Default Value: "EGPCS"
;   Development Value: "GPCS"
;   Production Value: "GPCS"". All of those lines have a ';' symbol at the beginning. No 'variables_order=EPGCS' line though. Also I should add that I'm using the php.ini-production as my php.ini file, as instructed by my PhpStorm software.

Comment: Have you tried making your submit input `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`? You usually need the `type` set to `submit` as I understand it...

Comment: @kunruh I did try using an input with a submit type but had the same results. Works with GET, doesn't work with POST.

Comment: @MuriloRM I recommend trying to strip it down to the simplest working version you can get. Comment out all your fields and just have one simple hard-coded input field (like `<input type="hidden" id="test" name="test" value="boo" />`). Then submit the form and `var_dump` the post array and see if that works.

Comment: @kunruh I'm currently working on that right now, will update the whole thread and replace it with a simple code sample instead in case the problem persists.

Comment: what's the web-server setup?

Comment: @rtfm I'm using a default WAMPP emulated server as I don't have much knowledge on the subject

Comment: seeing you mentioned phpstorm early .. goggle suggests  version 10.0.3 has a bug with POST (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999125-PhPStorm-10-does-not-allow-POST-method)

Comment: @rtfm I did have problems with my php setup prior to that though, so I had to install php from the official website and rename the **php.ini-production** default file to php.ini, as instructed by the phpStorm software

Comment: @rtfm jetbrains classify my phpStorm version as **Version: 2017.1.4** However, looking at the comments from the thread linked it appears that I'm not using my apache server by default which is a mistake. I still don't understand why would it work with the GET method but not the POST method though... Maybe related to the fact that the GET method sends parameters through the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Chrome

1. Go to index.html
2. Press f12. Developer tools will show up
3. Click Network
4. Tick Preserve Log and Disable Cache (I usually just do it that way)
5. From index.html click the submit button (do not close dev tools)
6. Go back to developer tools click 'teste.php'
7. Click headers, then expand general. You will see 'Request Method'. It should be POST

After working with @MuriloRM we ended up with the fundamental bug with PHPStorm

Please vote up the resolution of the issue 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000097930-Can-not-use-POST-method-in-PhpStorm

Comment: It does appear as post, but still I can't seem to be able to use any parameters. Isset function also returns false.

Comment: I understand you keep on testing that GET is successful and POST is not. What I'm trying to walk you through is isolating where the issue is.  Next step is check the actual payload sent.  Under 'Form Data' on dev tools. What was under it?

Comment: Ok now you are seeing the Form Data. If you have Fiddler install try to post from there.  This will now isolate if this is a transmission error between the browser and the server.

Comment: I have a parameter **nTesting: test** there. It's the exact same data I'm trying to send.

Comment: Are you running this on a server or you're running this locally? If you're running on a server do you use mod_rewrite?

Comment: I'm running it on a local emulated XAMPP server, but it came to my attention the possibility of my phpStorm be using something else instead of my Apache server, which is what I'm trying to investigate atm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148558/discussion-between-wsantos-and-murilorm).